# JOIN ON WITH MAX VALUE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, max

Hi guys i have a home work from school that i should show student with the highest score & the registrant id is even, sorry i can't show the structre of table because i don't know how to put them but i have 3 table

1. student
2. user
3. score

i have coding like this

```
SELECT student.id_student, name, role, status, no_phone, exam_status, score FROM student
JOIN user ON user.username = student.id_student
JOIN score ON score.id_student = student.id_student
WHERE mod(student.id_student, 2) = 0
ORDER BY score DESC
```

the result for registrant id is work, they show the registrant id even, but the scores show from the highest to the lowest, it should be show the highest only.

i want to use MAX but i dont know where can i put them.
can you guys help me fix this, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: If it's possible for you to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` syntax, then you definitely can get the table structure. And probably, posting the `SELECT version();` result can help a lot as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the max score per student you can aggregate the rows *before* joining:

```
select s.id_student, u.name, u.role, s.status, u.no_phone, s.exam_status, sc.score
from student s
join user u on u.username = s.id_student
join (
  select Max(score) as score, id_student
    from score
    group id_student
)sc on sc.id_student = s.id_student
where mod(s.id_student, 2) = 0
order by sc.score desc;
```

Note using short aliases for your tables improves the readability of the query; I guessed at which tables the columns are from - using aliases when joining tables means others, and you, don't need to guess.